# Blacklist specific requested URIs for Poltergeist so Capybara doesn't fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phantomjs, cucumber, capybara, poltergeist

Poltergeist accepts a `blacklist` and `whitelist` while configuring it as a driver for Capybara. The documentation states:

> Poltergeist supports URL blacklisting, which allows you to prevent scripts from running on designated domains.

While this is great, it doesn't help my issue where I would like to block certain assets from being requested/loaded as it is causing issues in my Travis-CI where those assets are returning as 500 Server Errors and causing my tests to fail even though they should be green.

URIs should be blocked as:
`['/stylesheet/*', 'some-image-name.jpg']`

Is this possible to do with Poltergeist? Or is there a way to have a Capybara cucumber test not fail just because an asset returned a 500 server error?

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  poltergeist_opts = {
    window_size: [1280, 1024],
    url_blacklist: ['/stylesheets/select_box_arrow.gif', '/stylesheets/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png']
  }

  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, poltergeist_opts)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Poltergeist blacklists are specified as wildcard strings (* and . as special characters) that are substring matched to the full urls being requested, so yes you can block the specific things you want by specifying exactly what you've shown in your question in the `url_blacklist` array.  However, if the 500 error is coming from your app you'd be much better off just fixing your app/test setup so that it doesn't return a server error when requesting valid assets (fix asset deploy on travis, etc).

The other option is to prevent Capybara from failing tests on server errors - `Capybara.raise_server_errors = false` - however that could possibly hide server errors you care about.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about `Capybara.raise_server_errors`. While not an ideal long-term solution, it will fix the problem midterm. I also tried `url_blacklist` in my configuration for Poltergeist, but it seems to still be fetching those assets. I've adjusted my question to include the relevant snippet.

Comment: @ManBearPixel hmm, it definitely should block them so not sure what's going wrong for you there. Do you have any before blocks that are resetting the blacklist? You can call `page.driver.network_traffic('blocked')` to get an array of all the blocked requests, and `page.driver.network_traffic` will give you the requests that weren't blocked.  You could look at those and compare the URLs and see if they're what you think they are.  The other question is why your server is returning a 500 for non-existent assets, that should really be 404 or something.

Comment: @ManBearPixel One other potential would be that you're not running a new enough version of Poltergeist to actually have blacklist support? What version of Poltergeist and PhantomJS are you using?

Comment: @ManBearPixel Additionally are you sure those assets are actually loaded from the URLs you think?  If using the rails asset pipeline those would normally be loaded as something like `/assets/<hash>-select_box_arrow.gif` in the test and production environments

Comment: Unfortunately I'm working with a monolithic app architecture which handles requests in a facepalm matter. Fortunately there is work being done to slowly migrate off our current routing but until then it is what it is. -- Where would I setup the page.driver.network_traffic? Would I run a `binding.pry` and call that method to investigate? -- Poltergeist is `v1.6.0` PhantomJS is `v1.9.8`. -- And yes, normally those would be in the normal asset pipeline, but as stated above... this is a special type of application architecture.

Comment: Correct -- add a binding pry and investigate, although the `blocked` option isn't supported in 1.6.0.  Ok so your versions of Poltergeist and PhantomJS are ancient.  Blacklist configuration in the driver config support, and wildcard support was added in 1.10.0, in 1.6.0 (February 05, 2015) you need to configure it during the test run and there is no support for wildcards